# Throwing Non-Custom Exceptions in API

Tags: java, api, exception

I'm writing an API and would like to throw an IOException.  I was taught that we should always wrap exceptions in custom exceptions in APIs.

Comment: Yes, you were taught right. What's your exact question?

Comment: I dont see a reason for having a custom exception if you actually encounter and want to report an IOException. What you can do is to chain your exception to give a better message: `catch (IOException ioe) { throw new IOException("Cannot read settings file=" + name, ioe); }`

Comment: @eckes OP means that you should wrap this `IOException` into a custom exception that extends from `RuntimeException` so your client code of your API is clean about using try-catch blocks.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza OP was not mentioning RuntimeException. Besides having unchecked exceptions is only in some circles regarded as good design for APIs.

Comment: No such rule or best practice of wrapping in custom exception in APIs. When developing APIs you need to evaluate what makes more sense to the client of the API, whether original exception or custom exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm writing an API and would like to throw an IOException.

That is just fine.  Go ahead and do it.

> I was taught that we should always wrap exceptions in custom exceptions in APIs.

If someone taught you that, they are just plain wrong.  It is generally considered *best practice* to use (e.g. throw) standard exceptions where they are applicable.

For example:

> 9) Use Standard Exceptions
>
> Our ninth Java best practice advise on using standard and inbuilt Java Exceptions. Using standard Exception instead of creating own Exception every now and then is much better in terms of maintenance and consistency. Reusing standard exception makes code more readable, because most of  Java developers are familiar with standard RuntimeException from JDK like, IllegalStateException, IllegalArgumentException or NullPointerException, and they will immediately be able to know purpose of Exception, instead of looking out another place on code or docs to find out purpose of user defined Exceptions.

Reference: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/0-exception-handling-best-practices-in-Java-Programming.html